# How to separate two regions of latlon data on python

Tags: python, linux, cluster-analysis

I am currently working with BUFR files with wind data. When I read this file on python I get 4 large vectors, latitude vector, longitude vector, wind_direction vector, and wind_speed vector.

Both wind vectors are masked python arrays because there is non-valid data. This happens because the data comes from a non-geostationary satellite. In fact I successfully generated the following image from this BUFR file to show you the general shape that the data takes.

[image: wind data]

In this image I have plotted a color field to represent the wind speed, while the arrows obviously represent the wind direction.

Please notice the two bands of actual data. Unfortunately the way I am plotting the data, generates a third band (where the color field is smooth), in-between the actual data bands. This is an artefact of the function `pcolormesh`. If I could superimpose two `pcolormesh plots, each one representing one of the bands, this problem would disappear.

Unfortunately, I do not know how I could separate the data "regions". I have thought about clustering techniques but do not know how to cluster along latlon data using ANOTHER array (the wind data) as the clustering rule.

This is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import bufr
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab

WIND_DIR_INDEX = 97
WIND_SPEED_INDEX = 96

bfrfile = sys.argv[1]
print bfrfile
bfr = bufr.BUFRFile(bfrfile)

lon = []
lat = []
wind_d = []
wind_s = []

for record in bfr:
    for entry in record:
        if entry.index == WIND_DIR_INDEX:
            wind_d.append(entry.data)
        if entry.index == WIND_SPEED_INDEX:
            wind_s.append(entry.data)
        if entry.name.find("LONGITUDE") == 0:
            lon.append(entry.data)
        if entry.name.find("LATITUDE") == 0:
            lat.append(entry.data)

lons = np.concatenate(lon)
lats = np.concatenate(lat)
winds_d = np.concatenate(wind_d)
winds_s = np.concatenate(wind_s)
winds_d = np.ma.masked_greater(winds_d,1.0e+6)
winds_s = np.ma.masked_greater(winds_s,1.0e+6)
windu = np.cos((winds_d-180)*(np.pi/180))
windv = np.sin((winds_d-180)*(np.pi/180))

# Data interpolation for pcolormesh (needs gridded data)
xi = np.linspace(lons.min(),lons.max(),lons.size/10)
yi = np.linspace(lats.min(),lats.max(),lats.size/10)
Z = mlab.griddata(lons,lats,winds_s,xi,yi)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

mydpi = 96
fig = plt.figure(frameon=True)
fig.set_size_inches(1600/mydpi,1200/mydpi)
ax = plt.Axes(fig,[0,0,1,1])
#ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)
plt.hold(True);


plt.quiver(lons[::5],lats[::5],windu[::5],windv[::5],linewidths=0)
for method in (ax.set_xticks,ax.set_xticklabels,ax.set_yticks,ax.set_yticklabels):
        method([])
        fig.savefig('/home/cendas/bin/python/bufr_ascat.png',bbox_inches=0,dpi=5*mydpi)

mydpi = 96
fig = plt.figure(frameon=True)
fig.set_size_inches(1600/mydpi,1200/mydpi)
ax = plt.Axes(fig,[0,0,1,1])
#ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)
plt.hold(True);
try:
    plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z,alpha=None)
    plt.clim(0,10)
except ValueError:
    pass
    print "Warning: Empty data array."

for method in (ax.set_xticks,ax.set_xticklabels,ax.set_yticks,ax.set_yticklabels):
    method([])
    fig.savefig('/home/cendas/bin/python/bufr_ascat_color.png',bbox_inches=0,dpi=5*mydpi)
```

I then usually follow this python code with the following  terminal commands to combine the images:

```
convert bufr_ascat.png  -transparent white bufr_ascat.png
convert bufr_ascat_color.png  -transparent white bufr_ascat_color.png
composite bufr_ascat.png bufr_ascat_color.png bufrascat.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't abuse clustering for this.

What you need is a simple selection / filtering; not a structure discovery process.

Choose the mean of the *masked* data. All non-masked data left of that mean is the left part, all non-masked data on the right is the other?

Clustering is the wrong tool for this task.